# You can use the /type/<type>/id/<id> pattern

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

In: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/empty_types/index.html

> **Using empty  types**
>
> You can use empty types in entities in NGSI9/NGSI10 operations. In
>   fact, convenience operations implicitly use empty types in this way by
>   default You can use the `/type<type>/id/<id>` pattern instead of 
>   in convenience operations URLs to specify a type).

How can I use `/type/<type>/id/<id>`?
Can be used with NGSI v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the syntax is sligthly different, e.g.:

```
GET /v2/entities/<id>?type=<type>
```